# How to listen on a port with Node.js http server behind Windows firewall without admin rights

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, sockets, admin

in my school we have a lot of computers connected to a Windows Domain.
I am writing a simple realtime chat in JavaScript with Node.js but when I try to start the server, Windows ask me the admin's username and password.
When I close this message the server starts but it's visible only on my computer. I have tried to run the server on Ubuntu with a VM, but if I set the "Attached to" field (in the Network panel) to "Bridged adapters" the DHCP server assigns the IP (10.13.100.X subnet mask is 255.255.0.0, my computer ip is 10.13.0.X with the same subnet mask) but the server isn't visible (in no computer), if I set the field to "NAT", Windows ask me the admin's username and password.

**N.B.** My server use zero-conf (the node library is `bonjour`[link to npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bonjour)) for the server configuration on the clients and web sockets for the communication between clients and server.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT** The computers are connected with ethernet cable. I know is the local firewall is blocking the ports.

Comment: can you use a port like `8080` instead of `80` ? then you should be able to connect from a browser like `http://10.13.0.5:8080/path/name.ext`

Comment: Yes, I've tried, but when I run the server on the computer it's visible only for me, if i run on the VM it isn't visible for all the users.

Answer (score 0):

it could be local firewall is blocking port.
It also depends how your connected to the neetwork. Wifi usually doesn't allow local traffic.

Comment: The computers are connected with ethernet cable.

Comment: wifi (and all networks for that matter) always allows local traffic, not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: try tracert the IP to see what it goes through.  (traceroute)  Also try accessing the link locally to see if that works. If it works local, and not remote, then it sounds like a router is between you and the other connected computer which many times will not allow incoming traffic.  for example "http://x.x.x.x:port/api/command"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the default HTTP port `80`?

Comment: Yes, it's disabled

Comment: Also try to add `node` to the environment path of Windows.
You need to close and reopen any command prompt after the change, before calling your node server.